# Collapsing select groups

Tags: r, performance

I am trying to find a faster method to iteratively collapse selected groups in a data frame.  I am currently looping over acquisitions, dates and variables.  I would like to vectorize this if possible.

Given a set of ids [1,2], I would like to take all values for id 2, and add it to id1.  Additionally, I would like to remove id2 from the dataset after this.

## Generate data to be adjusted

```
dates <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
ids <- c(1,2,3,4)
x1 <- seq(from=1, by=1, length=16)
x2 <- seq(from=1, by=2, length=16)
dat <- expand.grid(dates=dates, ids=ids)
dat <- data.frame(dat, x1, x2)
```

## Generate data to adjust by

```
ref <- data.frame(acquirer=c(2,3), acquired=c(1,4))
```

## slow triple for to iteratively collapse

```
for(i in 1:nrow(ref)){
  for(j in c("x1", "x2")){
    for(z in c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")){
      dat[dat$ids==ref$acquirer[i] & dat$dates==z, j] <- 
          dat[dat$ids==ref$acquirer[i] & dat$dates==z, j] +
          dat[dat$ids==ref$acquired[i] & dat$dates==z, j]
      dat[dat$ids==ref$acquired[i] & dat$dates==z, j] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the case of collapsing 2 into 1:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(ids = if_else(ids == 2, 1, ids)) %>% 
  group_by(ids, dates) %>% 
  summarize(x1 = sum(x1), x2 = sum(x2))
```

You can add another mutate or use a `case_when` call if there are multiple recodes.

Comment: This idea works, thank you.  Would case_when prevent me from having to loop over the ref data?  Could you provide brief example code?  I would also like to summarize across all variables except id, date.  Is there a way to use summarize as such  summarize(setdiff(names(dat), c("ids", dates")) = sum(setdiff(names(dat), c("ids", "dates")))

Comment: Can you post some sample data for the application you are thinking about?

Comment: Using the above data, I am now doing this:  ```sumVars <- c("x1", "x2")  for(i in 1:nrow(ref)){dat <- dat %>% mutate(id = ifelse(id==ref$acquired[i], ref$acquiree[i], id)) %>% group_by(ids, dates) %>% summarize_at(vars(sumVars), sum, na.rm=T) %>% ungroup()} ```  However, this is slower than the nested for loop process described above.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
setDT(ref)

#join the acquirer and acquired into a data.table and calculate x1 and x2 values
acqDat <- dat[dat[ref, on=.(ids=acquirer), allow.cartesian=TRUE],
    on=.(dates, ids=acquired), allow.cartesian=TRUE,
    .(dates, ids=i.ids, x1=x1+i.x1, x2=x2+i.x2)]

#update by reference the updated x1 and x2 values
dat[, c("x1", "x2") := acqDat[copy(.SD), on=.(dates, ids), .(x1, x2)]]
```

output:

```
    dates ids x1 x2
 1:    Q1   1 NA NA
 2:    Q2   1 NA NA
 3:    Q3   1 NA NA
 4:    Q4   1 NA NA
 5:    Q1   2  6 10
 6:    Q2   2  8 14
 7:    Q3   2 10 18
 8:    Q4   2 12 22
 9:    Q1   3 22 42
10:    Q2   3 24 46
11:    Q3   3 26 50
12:    Q4   3 28 54
13:    Q1   4 NA NA
14:    Q2   4 NA NA
15:    Q3   4 NA NA
16:    Q4   4 NA NA
```